# Mule: Maven unable to download mule-module-publish-subscribe dependencies

Tags: maven, module, mule, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement simple mule-module-publish-subscribe example. I've added following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mule-ee-snapshots</id>
        <name>Mule Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repsitory>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-publish-subscribe</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I got following error, while building the project. It looks like dev.ee.mulesource is unreachable. I'm using mule ee version.

Downloading: http://dev.ee.mulesource.com/repository/content/repositories/snapshots/org/mule/modules/mule-module-publish-subscribe/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Aug 15, 2014 11:07:45 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable

Any idea to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following repository location.

```
https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/
```

This location is accesible and has the Publish-Subscribe modile availabel in it.

```
https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/mule/modules/mule-module-publish-subscribe/
```

If this doens't work then you might copy the jar to your local Maven repo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, now it able to build. But now getting another error like it's not able to find xsd path for mule-pubsub. Error: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pubsub/current/mule-pubsub.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.  Any idea about this srror?

Comment: mule config: http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pubsub http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pubsub/current/mule-pubsub.xsd

Comment: Create a new question with your new issue. This way others who are searching for this kind of issue will be able to find the solution easily.

Comment: Sure, I've created new question.